# Easist way to remove spots from binary image

Tags: image

I have a 1 dimensional array of binary image data 1's and 0's. I am attempting to implement a labeling algorithm to remove small objects from the image. However, I am wondering what other methods there are for removing small spots.

eg.
image_array[] = { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, . . . 1, 1, 1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, "by small spots", you mean [impulse noise (aka, "salt and pepper" noise)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_noise#Salt-and-pepper_noise), then you could simply just [implement a median filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter). In the case of an array like so:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

The result would become:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

So, any impulse noise is gone. Additionally, you can greatly improve your results via [**adaptive** median filtering](http://www.giassa.net/?page_id=639). This approach has the added benefit of detecting, in advance, if a pixel really is noisy, and needs to be filtered, or it is just a statistical outlier that can be safely ignored.

If the spots are bigger than a single pixel, you just use a larger median filter kernel. For spots `m x m` in side, you just need a median filter kernel of size `(2m)+1`. So, for 1x1 pixel sized spots, you just a 3x3 (or in your case, 3x1), and so on.